# hiding sub folders from url display

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have my pages categorized as below....
Main index.html is in the root, so this displays when the domain is entered into a browser.
May pages are categorized as below...

```
/Pages/Automotive/Ford/Mustang/*.html
/Pages/Automotive/Chevy/Camaro/*.html
/Pages/Automotive/Dodge/Charger/*.html
```

etc...

What I am looking for  is a way to hide the subfolders from the url in the browser..
So, if a link, shortcut, or page is at the following:

```
/Pages/Automotive/Ford/Mustang/Main.html
```

The following is displayed in the url status bar on the browser...

```
/Ford/Mustang/Main.html
```

or even

```
/Mustang/Main.html
```

Basically masking the `/Pages/Automotive/` Sub Directories.
And, if a this is entered in the browser:

```
/Ford/Mustang/Main.html
```

Then, the original page is still displayed at

```
/Pages/Automotive/Ford/Mustang/Main.html
```

Is this doable? If so how, I have looked into .htaccess, but I haven't found what I need..
I am also using 1and1 as my hosting company..

Comment: Yes it is possible. But you should avoid having many urls leading to same content (duplicate content is not a friend of search engines)